# How can I make screen start at 1 when launching?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I run screen, I usually just leave the "0th" screen empty.  This is mostly because I get used to reaching over to the left side of the keyboard to select screens (ex C-a 1, C-a 2, etc).  Is there a way to just make screen start at 1 and use 0 *after* 9?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your .screenrc

```
# Window numbering starts at 1, not 0.
bind c screen 1
bind 0 select 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I forget the exact syntax, but if you run `man screen`, you should find what you need to put in your `.screenrc` to do that. If you google, there's many examples of screenrcs that do it.

Comment: Answers that tell you to Google the question are not answers, especially since this is the first link found by Google.